# Graphic format. SVG PNG or something else

Tags: android, image-format

I need some advice on the choice of graphic format.
My task is to make pictures for the mobile application from existing Autocad files (DWG format).
These pictures will be used in the application interface.
I did some research and found a way to convert DWG to PNG or SVG.
For illustration purposes, I have attached a picture.
The SVG format looks preferable. Since it is a vector format, the picture is of higher quality.
At the same time, SVG has a disadvantage, compared to PNG it weighs 4 times more.
In this example, SVG weighs 86 kb, PNG 22 kb.
Since there should be about 1000 pictures, this will greatly affect the final size of the application.
In this regard, I have 2 questions:

1. Is there any way to reduce the size of an SVG file without affecting the quality? All the pictures, like this example and the same color.
2. Are there any other alternatives to SVG, i.e. other vector extensions that Android supports?
   Thanks in advance for reply.[image]

SVG FILE:
https://svgshare.com/i/ddq.svg

Comment: There are several ways, but few are generalizable as there are different types of images. If all your images are the same, it's best if you share one in the question to analyze it in detail.

Comment: Hi Danielillo, I attached link to svg file  in the question

Comment: *How* are the pictures going to be used?  Will the user be able to zoom in on them?  If not, then the quality difference isn't likely to matter much.  In addition to file size, since there will be *many* of them, you also should consider rendering time.  1000+ SVG files be slower (and consume more battery) to render.

Answer (score 4):

With an online SVG optimizer = 46 kb

[image]

It depends on the final destination of each image. If it were a personal project, knowing that I would only use the vector information, I would not hesitate to use a compressed PDF = 20 kb

A PDF saves all vector information and vector drawing programs can open it fully editable.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this valuable response.

I would like to clarify your answer a bit. Is it possible to use PDF files as integral graphics inside a mobile app? In the app I plan to make, the User will click them. These images are used to navigate to the following functions. 

I saw you managed to successfully compress an SVG file, could you please tell me what this online service is.

Comment: There are tons, Google Search: "SVG online optimizer"

Comment: What do you mean by *integral graphics*? The user will work with the image vectors in the mobile app or just click to visualize them?

Comment: I wanted to say that the User will not use these svg images.
This is only to illustrate the source file, which is also included in the application.

I found this online service.
It works well. Good thinking!